# Get the max value over the window in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am getting the maximum value over a specific window in pyspark. But what is returned from the method is not the expected.

Here comes my codes:

```
test = spark.createDataFrame(DataFrame({'grp': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'val': [2, 3, 3, 4]}))
win = Window.partitionBy('grp').orderBy('val')
test = test.withColumn('row_number', F.row_number().over(win))
test = test.withColumn('max_row_number', F.max('row_number').over(win))
display(test)
```

And the output is:

[image]

I expected it would return 2 for both group "a" and group "b" but it didn't.

Anyone has ideas on this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is with the frame for the `max` function. If you order the window as you are doing the frame is going to be `Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow`. So you can define another window where you drop the order (because the max function doesn't need it):

```
w2 = Window.partitionBy('grp')
```

You can see that in PySpark [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html):

> Note When ordering is not defined, an unbounded window frame (rowFrame, unboundedPreceding, unboundedFollowing) is used by default. When ordering is defined, a growing window frame (rangeFrame, unboundedPreceding, currentRow) is used by default.

Comment: Updated docs link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html